Key Input Freezing After Switching Directions
When I hold down the right key and then press the left key immediately after, the left key responds only once and then freezes.
Code:
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const FooApp());
}

class FooApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: FooFlameGame.new),
    );
  }
}

class FooFlameGame extends FlameGame with KeyboardEvents {
  late final TextComponent textComponent;
  final stopwatch = Stopwatch();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    stopwatch.start();

    textComponent = TextComponent(
      position: Vector2(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5),
      anchor: Anchor.center,
    );
    await add(textComponent);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);


  }

  @override
  KeyEventResult onKeyEvent(
    KeyEvent event,
    Set<LogicalKeyboardKey> keysPressed,
  ) {
    final debugNames = keysPressed.map((e) => e.debugName,);
    final debugText = "${stopwatch.elapsed}: $debugNames";
    textComponent.text = debugText;
    print(debugText);

    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }
}

Result:
0:00:15.970799: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.471199: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.557799: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.640799: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.725500: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.807399: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.892399: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.974899: (Arrow Right)
0:00:17.059000: (Arrow Right)
0:00:17.086000: ()
0:00:17.088100: (Arrow Left)
0:00:17.591500: (Arrow Left)
0:00:17.674500: (Arrow Left)
0:00:17.758500: (Arrow Left)
0:00:17.841899: (Arrow Left)
0:00:17.917500: ()

There is a gap of approximately 0.5 between the first and second left key inputs. After that, the interval is about 0.1.
0:00:16.892399: (Arrow Right)
0:00:16.974899: (Arrow Right)
0:00:17.059000: (Arrow Right)
0:00:17.086000: ()
0:00:17.088100: (Arrow Left) <---------
0:00:17.591500: (Arrow Left) <---------
0:00:17.674500: (Arrow Left)

Is this a specification of the library or something?
Since this is for a game, I want it to respond quickly. Are there any workarounds for this?
The issue occurred regardless of whether I ran it on macOS or Chrome.
